# Cell duplicates image when append to content in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is a stupid but frustrating problem. I display a warning image as next to the invoice number for certain criteria but when I append the image to the content of the cell is seems to duplicates to the content size of the cell. 
If the cell doesn't have enough space it only displays once. I tried setting it as a background image with no-repeat enter image description hererepeat. It is JUST when you append it to ANY cell's content - I've tried them all. See image

I would really appreciate any help!

```
string sImage = "";
if (hWarningInd.Value == "Y") { 
   sImage = "<img src='Images/warning.png' style='border:none;' width='16' Title='" + hSARSMessage.Value + "' />"; 
}
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = e.Row.Cells[6].Text + sImage;
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `e.Row.Cells[6].Text` before you append `sImage`?

Comment: Where you have written this code? can you post the complete method/event for this code.

Comment: I am setting it to open the maintenance page with several parameters e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "<a href='MaintenanceCommercial.aspx?ExporterID=" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString() + "&ComId=" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[3].ToString() + "'" + sStyle + " Title='" + hSARSMessage.Value + "'>" + e.Row.Cells[6].Text +  "</a>";

Comment: @Bharadwaj it is a huge piece of code but basically it is in the gridview_rowdatabound event

Comment: Right click on the image in chrome browser and see if it is adding two `img` tags in a cell. If not then reduce the `width` for this `img` tag.